# render a div conditionally using props in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-props

I'm very new to react and I'm trying to show a message after I have submitted a post response, but it's not showing it.

Note: the `POST` response is working correctly. The message needs to show when the status in the app.js gets updated. It looks like the value of status is getting passed down only once when the pages renders for the first time.

**APP.JS**

```
class App extends Component {
  status = null;
  submit = async values => {
    const response = await providers.post('/providers/', {
      params: {
        values
      }
    });
    this.status = response.status;
    if (this.status === 200) {
      this.getInitialValues();
      this.myFormRef.reset();
    } else {
      console.log('ERROR: There was an error creating a new Provider');
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='registration-form ui container'>
        <img src={logo} alt={logo} />
        <h1>New Provider Form</h1>
        <Form
          onSubmit={this.submit}
          initialValues={this.getInitialValues()}
          ref={el => (this.myFormRef = el)}
        />
        <Status status={this.status} />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

**STATUS.JS**

```
import React from 'react';
const Status = props => {
  console.log(props.status);
  if (props.status === 200) {
    return <div className='status'>Provider Successfully Registered!</div>;
  } else if (props.status > 200) {
    return <div className='status'>ERROR: Couldn't register new provider</div>;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
};

export default Status;
```

Comment: Status is just an instance variable in `App`, so changing it won't cause anything to re-render. You gotta put it in `App`'s state, and update it with `setState()`, which will trigger a re-render.

Comment: Why don't you use `state` for `status`?

Comment: @Jayce444  that worked! I was trying it before I saw your comment. Sorry I'm very new at react as  you can see. Thanks so much!

Comment: @zynkn yep that was it. Thanks so much!

Comment: Feel free to post the answer so y'all get the points!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use state for re-render

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    status: '',
  };
  submit = async values => {
    const response = await providers.post('/providers/', {
      params: {
        values
      }
    });
    this.setState({
      status: response.status,
    });
    //this.status = response.status;
    if (response.status === 200) {
      this.getInitialValues();
      this.myFormRef.reset();
    } else {
      console.log('ERROR: There was an error creating a new Provider');
    }
  };
  render() {
    return (
     ...
     <Status status = {this.state.status}/>
     ...
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to show any updated state in react js, you have to render that variable using state. Because when you do setState in react, it automatically re-renders the component.
So, you can save your status in state like this:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      status: '',
    };
  }

submit = async (values) => {
    const response = await providers.post('/providers/', {
      params: {
        values
      }
    });
    this.setState({status: response.status},()=>{
       if (this.state.status === 200) {
         this.getInitialValues();
         this.myFormRef.reset();
       } else {
         console.log('ERROR: There was an error creating a new Provider');
       }
    });

  };
render() {
    return (
      <div className='registration-form ui container'>
        <img src={logo} alt={logo} />
        <h1>New Provider Form</h1>
        <Form
          onSubmit={this.submit}
          initialValues={this.getInitialValues()}
          ref={el => (this.myFormRef = el)}
        />
        <Status status={this.state.status} />
      </div>
    );
}
```

Hope this helps!!